# Генерация id для материалов на сайте

Tags: php, алгоритм

Надо скрыть настоящий auto increment id, и присваивать всем новостям свой id числового/буквенного вида, чтобы исключить автоперебор всех новостей

Идеальным примером служит генератор id у ютьюб.

Comment: а контрольная сумма не подойдет?

Comment: Любой ГСЧ/хэш чего-то и т.д. Плюс, конечно, сохранение уже сгенерированных id для исключения повторов.

Comment: Как вариант, timestamp. Всегда уникальный.

Comment: Или же просто преобразовывай названия в транслит и все недопустимые символы заменяй тире.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Специально для этого существует удобная библиотека: [hashids](https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.php).

Суть в том, что вы оставляете id в базе как есть, а на сайт выводите id, закодированные этой библиотекой.

При необходимости вы можете раскодировать id обратно в число, но никто кроме вас сделать это не может,  так как для этого требуется ваш секретный ключ.

Пример:

```
$hashids = new Hashids('my secret key'); 
$id = $hashids->encode(1, 2, 3); // o2fXhV 
$numbers = $hashids->decode($id); // [1, 2, 3]
```

Необходимо учитывать, что это не криптографическая библиотека, поэтому для шифрования данных на том уровне, который требуется для криптографии, она не подходит. Но с задачей сокрытия id она справляется отлично.

Answer (score 0):

Можно взять любой алгоритм шифрования, можно и из тех, что сейчас считаются не криптостойкими. Симметричное шифрование подойдёт отлично, ключ всё равно зашит только в приложении и его не надо никуда передавать. Показывать ссылки зашифрованные, перед обращением к БД вы можете расшифровать и получить исходный id. При ошибке расшифровки можете сразу 404 показывать, не пиная хранилище. Плюс этого способа в том, что не нужно хранить соответствие ссылки и id, невозможность прямого перебора и неясность формирования обеспечивается базовым требованием к криптографии, коллизии полученных шифрованных строк так же исключены. Если шифровать строку бинарного представления id - то есть 4 или 8 байта (int и bigint соответственно), то результирующая шифрованная строка будет постоянной длины. А имея лишь набор шифрованных строк в URL понять, что же именно и как зашифровано - невозможно. Если зашифрованная строка от 4 байт получилась слишком короткая - всегда можно добавить для объёма какие-нибудь посторонние данные.

Либо, можно сохранять соответствие какого-то случайного идентификатора непосредственно в СУБД. Например, UUID, или хэш от чего-нибудь. За коллизиями приглядывать придётся самостоятельно. Зато возможно как угодно менять идентификатор и делать его любой длины и формы.